# Limiting a text object in Crystal reports to 50 characters

Tags: object, text, formatting, crystal-reports-2008

I have created a text object and I want it to have a maximum of 50 characters only. Is there anyway I could do it using a formula? I do not know how to refer to a text object within a formula. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why 50 characters?  Is there a certain formatting that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a text object in a formula, but you can embed a formula in text object.  Your formula could be set to 50 characters.